# JSF selectManyListbox shows error of value binding

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, selectmanylistbox

I am using JSF tag **h:selectManyListbox** in JSP to display a list of items from a bean.

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{settingsBean.statusIds}" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;">
    <f:selectItem value="#{settingsBean.statusItems}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

The **statusItems** object is defined in the following bean class:

**SettingsBean.java**

```
public class SettingsBean {
   private List<String> statusIds;
   private List<SelectItem> statusItems;

   public SettingsBean() {
       initStatus();
   }    

   private void initStatus() {
       statusItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

       statusItems.add(new SelectItem("v1", "lbl1"));
       statusItems.add(new SelectItem("v2", "lbl2"));
       statusItems.add(new SelectItem("v3", "lbl3"));
   }

   public ArrayList getStatusItems(){
       return getStatusItemsList(false);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   private ArrayList getStatusItemsList(boolean selected) {
       ArrayList ids = new ArrayList();     
       if (!selected) {
           boolean inSelIds = false;
           for (int i=0; i < statusItems.size(); i++) {
               inSelIds = false;
               SelectItem item = (SelectItem)statusItems.get(i);

               if (selected==inSelIds) {
                   String text = item.getLabel();                   
                   //ids.add(text);
                   ids.add(new SelectItem(item.getValue(), text));
               }
           }
       }

       return ids;
   }
}
```

But I am getting an error message when loading this:

---

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value binding '#{settingsBean.statusItems}' of UISelectItem : {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/Settings.jsp][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectManyListbox,Id: _id3][Class: javax.faces.component.UISelectItem,Id: _id4]} does not reference an Object of type SelectItem
```

What should I be missing or causing this problem? Thank you for your help

Comment: it's a type of object problem you are using a type of data instead of an other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSF we have two different tags `selectItem` and `selectItems`. `selectItem` is used to display single item, although we can use multiple `selectItem` tags to show multiple values. But if we have a list of `selectItems` then we should use `selectItems` rather than `selectItem`. So replace you `selectItem` tag on your XHTML with the `selectItems` like below:

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{settingsBean.statusIds}" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{settingsBean.statusItems}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

Comment: @NJ Francisco : Have you generated Setter/Getter for statusIds?

Answer (score -1):

Your binding is not quite correct. In this case you need to use either a Collection or an Array as in the example:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_selectmanylistbox_tag.htm

Besides you should consider replace the value="value" attribute from

```
<f:selectItem value="#{settingsBean.statusItems}" />
```

To:

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{settingsBean.statusItems}" />
```